# how do i associate a domain name with a .mac account

Tags: iweb, domain

i built a website using iweb and posted it to my .mac account.  so i can go to web.mac.com/... and see my site.   i now just purchased a domain name and i want to associate the domain name with this website.  what do i need to do to link these together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like MobileMe does allow a custom domain name.  [Here are instructions from Apple to set up a MobileMe website with a custom domain name](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1107).  All you need to be able to do is create a custom CNAME record for your domain, then set your domain name in MobileMe.

If you don't already have a domain name registered, I can highly recommend [GoDaddy](http://www.godaddy.com).  I haven't had any problems with them and they do have great prices.

Answer (score 0):

DNS (domain name service) can only resolve domains and subdomains, but not URLs. Domain forwarding will not work. You can try various tricks for masking or embedding, but there is no good solution for this imho.